# Writing dictionary to text file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

how to write to file dictionary in format:

```
d={'a':b,c,d,e,f}
```

to write to a text file in format

```
a|b|c|d|e|f
```

Comment: Your dictionnary has a single key, it would be more interesting to give an example with multiple keys.

Comment: You should show some code you have tried that is not working.  This isn't a place to just have people write your code for you.

Comment: So is `a` the key and the values are a list of `[b, c, d, e, f]`?

Comment: @Drewness technically, that's a tuple ;)

Comment: @adsmith - Yeah, I couldn't figure out if he wrote it the way he _meant_ to or what...

Comment: So your dictionary has the key `"a"` with the string value `"b,c,d,e,f"`, is that right?

Comment: OP may have also meant `{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}`.  Editing the question without getting clarification there probably not a good idea.

Comment: @F.J I rolled back the change. That edit may have been right, but just as easily confused things as clarified them. Let's wait for OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as outf:
    for key,values in d.iteritems():
        outf.write("|".join([key]+values) + "\n")
```

then to reload,

```
d = {}
with open("output.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        values = line.rstrip("\r\n").split("|")
        key = values.pop(0)
        d[key] = values
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm speculating here, but I think you want a `list` (not a `dict`).

```
ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] # also ls = list("abcdef")
```

You can write it to a file like this:

```
f = open("file", "w")
f.write("|".join(ls))
f.close()
```